# Как можно понизить пропускную способность локальной сети средствами Windows?

Tags: windows, сеть

Стоит такая задача:

1. Есть приложение где транслируется видео с камеры (на одной машине сервер, на другой само приложение)
2. Необходимо создать ситуацию, при которой в приложение будет приходить неравномерное количество кадров. Т.е. 0.5 секунд кадров нет, а потом сразу 25 кадров приходит

Для воспроизведения такой ситуации, коллеги советуют понизить пропускную способность сети. Но не могу понять каким образом. 
Пытался с помощью powershel понизить скорость след. командой:
`New-NetQosPolicy -Name "FileCopy" -SMB -ThrottleRateActionBitsPerSecond 10MB`но результат это не дало. 
Пробовал также в планировщике пакетов QoS увеличить ограничение резервируемой пропускной способности. Результат так же нулевой.

Answer (score 7):

Понижение скорости работает - но не отражает полного спектра возможных сетевых проблем.

Для более полного тестирования системы в условиях нестабильной связи я бы рекомендовал настроить виртуалку с Линуксом на борту (рекомендую дистрибутив debian, стабильную ветку, без gui), которой бы дал доступ одновременно к "реальной" сети в режиме моста - и к отдельной закрытой сети.

В таком случае виртуалку можно настроить как маршрутизатор между этими двумя сетями, пробросив порт с нее на хост-компьютер через закрытую сеть. А дальше можно использовать модуль `tc` для `iptables`, который умеет создавать полный спектр сетевых проблем:

- ограничение скорости;
- случайные потери пакетов;
- приход пакетов не в том порядке;
- дублирование пакетов;

Answer (score 0):

После написания вопроса сразу обнаружил способ понижения пропускной сети. И способ оказался невероятно простым.

Необходимо зайти в настройки сети "Свойства"-выбрать "Клиент для сетей Microsoft" - нажать на "Настроить" - "Дополнительно" - в списку выбрать "Скорость и дуплекс" и выбрать ограничение в 10мб

Comment: Это свойства не "Клиента для сетей Microsoft", а самой сетевой карты, точнее, её драйвера. И эта настройка есть не у всех драйверов.

Comment: Но собственно мне такой подход помог в решении задачи. 
Но если есть еще какой-то способ средставми Windows ограничить скорость, могли бы его описать? ?

Comment: И как это поможет смоделировать ситуацию "0.5 секунд кадров нет, а потом сразу 25 кадров приходит"? Вы думаете, что решили задачу -- а на деле решили другую, с иной формулировкой. Виртуалка с tc в этом плане не создаёт ложной иллюзии, что вы смоделировали ситуацию.